# Android : How to get callback from custom method?

Tags: java, android

I have the following class:

```
public class TimerTaskHelper {

    private static TimerTaskHelper instance = null;
    private static Integer ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
    private static Handler handler;
    private static Runnable runnableInstance;
    private static Container container;

    public static TimerTaskHelper getInstance(Container c) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new TimerTaskHelper(c);
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public TimerTaskHelper(Container c) {
        this.handler =  new Handler();
        this.runnableInstance = runnableCode;
        this.container = c;
        // Kick off the first runnableInstance task right away
        handler.post(runnableCode);
    }

    // Define the task to be run here
    private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Do something here on the main thread
            Logger.d("Called");
            // Repeat this runnableInstance code again every 2 seconds
            handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
            container.notifyObservers();
        }
    };

    public void stopExecution() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnableInstance);
        instance = null;
    }

}
```

I'm able to get instance from controller using the:

```
mTimerTaskHelper = TimerTaskHelper.getInstance(container);
```

But i would like to get callback in controller after the each

```
   private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
```

and

```
public void stopExecution() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnableInstance);
        instance = null;
    }
```

From controller.

How can i do it in the best way please?

Comment: First thing: what is the point of making your attributes ... static?!

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to something like this.

```
interface CallBack {
void callBackMethod();
}

public class TimerTaskHelper {

private static TimerTaskHelper instance = null;
private static Integer ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
private static Handler handler;
private static Runnable runnableInstance;
private static Container container;
private CallBack callback;
public void setCallBack(CallBack cb){
 callback=cb;
}
public static TimerTaskHelper getInstance(Container c) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new TimerTaskHelper(c);
    }
    return instance;
}

public TimerTaskHelper(Container c) {
    this.handler =  new Handler();
    this.runnableInstance = runnableCode;
    this.container = c;
    // Kick off the first runnableInstance task right away
    handler.post(runnableCode);
}

// Define the task to be run here
private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something here on the main thread
        Logger.d("Called");
        // Repeat this runnableInstance code again every 2 seconds
        handler.postDelayed(runnableCode, 2000);
        container.notifyObservers();
        if(callback!=null){
           callback.callBackMethod();
    }
};
  mTimerTaskHelper = TimerTaskHelper.getInstance(container);
  mTimerTaskHelper.setCallBack(new CallBack(){
  void callBackMethod(){
  //TODO your code
  }});
```